# How could I replace a section of Unicode?

Tags: python, replace, unicode, replit

How could I replace a section of Unicode? such as D800 through DB7F? I've asked the built-in replit ai for some help but its not doing much. this is the best result:

```
text = =('there's more code to link this var to a file but thats not important')
newtext = text.replace(r'\uE000', '#').replace(r'\uF8FF', '#').replace(r'\uDC00', '#').replace(r'\uDFFF', '#').replace(r'\uD800', '#').replace(r'\uDB7F', '#').replace(r'\uDB80', '#').replace(r'\uDBFF', '#')
```

I've tried asking AI (replit built-in), others around the replit community, and searching on google, but I've found nothing.

Comment: You'll have to do it character by character.  You could set up a translation dictionary to make that easier.  `newtext = ''.join(mapping.get(c,c) for c in text)`.

Comment: Warning: such section is not real Unicode. Unicode has it reserved for surrogates (to build emoji and other characters with codepoint above 0xFFFF). Python uses such part as *surrogateescape* (to encode bytes which are illegal in Unicode, as one could have, e.g. reading from `sys.argv`, or environmental variables. So you should be careful. Or you should encode in UTF-16, and then working with the code units.

Comment: Do you really want to replace them instead of showing the character they are pointing at?

Comment: 1: well that will probably suck..
2: I know that. that's the issue, i don't need the looks of the unicode, i just need the "data" of it, "out off all the unicode characters, which one is this?" i run into a problem where it will point to a character, then then translate it to just one. Other words it will change a range of unicode characters to only on, which will hurt my code.
3: Yes, i want it to change in the meantime i look for a replacement, it could be simpler to only replace all the space that converts a character to just "�" (U+FFFD)

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to match a range:

```py
import re

text = 'test\udc00\udc01\udc02\uf8ff\ue000test'

result = re.sub(r'[\ud800-\udfff\ue000\uf8ff]', '#', text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
test#####test
```

In case you actually have *literal* Unicode escapes in your code, below would first translate the escape codes to Unicode characters:

```py
import re

text = r'test\udc00\udc01\udc02\uf8ff\ue000test' # literal escapes (raw string)
#text = 'test\udc00\udc01\udc02\uf8ff\ue000test'  # Unicode characters

# capture 4-digit hexadecimal escape and convert to Unicode
convert = re.sub(r'\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), text)

result = re.sub(r'[\ud800-\udfff\uf8ff\ue000]', '#', convert)
print(result)
```

Comment: what would it look like if i changed all the replacement characters¹ to hashtags?

¹: ����

Comment: @SomePerson Not sure what you mean.  Make a clearer example.

Comment: I want it to replace unicode characters \uE000 through \uF8FF, \uDC00 through \uDFFF, \uD800 through \uDB7F, and \uDB80 through \uDBFF. I want to be all replaced with a hashtag (#). the unicode characters is also "fluid" which means it changes, and i want the code to adapt to that, so no matter what the text file says (which the "text" var will be and doesnt need to change), it will do it.

Comment: @SomePerson so put those ranges in the regular expression

Comment: Okay im trying but im having a hard time implementing it.  specifically line 5 at "r'\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})'" right now i have the text as the contents of a txt file and i can't really ctrl+c, ctrl+v because of how long it is. how do i change it so that it looks at the var?

Comment: @SomePerson so you have literal escape strings?  Please give a *sample* of your input, not all of it. Edit your question.